# Adding tuple to as keys dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I'm trying to add a tuple as values, while iterating through the list of keys in a dictionary.  I'm sure there's a way to do it with list comprehension, but I couldn't get it to work in the keys.
For simplicity's sake, here is the concept:

```
myDict = {"Last name", "First name"}
myTuple = ("Miller", "Joe")
for key in myDict:
    myDict.update(zip({key:n for n in myTuple}))
```

Comment: Is that actually how your `myDict` looks like? Because as is that is not a dictionary. That is a set.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What's your excepted output? Do you mean something like `{'First name': 'Miller', 'Last name': 'Joe'}   # dict(zip(myDict, myTuple))`? Or `[{'First name': 'Miller'}, {'Last name': 'Joe'}] # [dict([i]) for i in zip(myDict, myTuple)]`?

Comment: Dictionary without values...is that where i screwed up? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `myDict` is a `set`, not a `dict`. Using curly braces (`{}`) without any values will result in a `set`. The problem with `set`s is they are not ordered. You can simply do this if you change both to `tuples` (or `list`s, for this purpose):

```
myKeys = ("Last name", "First name")
myValues = ("Miller", "Joe")
print(dict(zip(myKeys, myValues)))
```

which will print the following dict:

```
{'Last name': 'Miller', 'First name': 'Joe'}
```

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​"The problem with sets is they are not ordered" - note that `dict`s are also not ordered.

Comment: Wow, thanks...lol...that's what I missed. I'll mark soon as it lets me.

Comment: @KevinGuan It does not matter here as the only `dict` is the result.